# Bool value at abstract class wont change

Tags: c#, .net, class

I wrote a MySQL Connection and Queries Classes they both check Connected state from Baglanti Class but the value wont updated here is my classes.
This is Baglanti Class

```
abstract class Baglanti
{
    protected MySqlConnection connDB
    { get; set; }
    public bool Connected { get; set; }
}
```

The Connection Class

```
class DB : Baglanti
{
    private LogStream Writer { get; set; }
    public void Baglan()
    {
        Writer = new LogStream();
        var uid = "*****";
        var pwd = "*****";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=****;" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + pwd + ";";
        connDB = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            base.Connected = true;
            Writer.Info_Log("Veritabanı Bağlantısı Kuruldu.");
        }
        else { base.Connected = false; }
    }
    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connDB.Open();
            base.Connected = true;
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    Writer.Hata_Log("Veritabanına bağlantı kurulamadı.");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    Writer.Hata_Log("Veritabanı Kullanıcı-Şifre Hatası.");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And This is Queries Class

```
 class Islem : Baglanti
{
    private LogStream Writer { get; set; }
    public Islem()
    {
        Writer = new LogStream();
    }
    public bool GirisKontrol(string id,string pw)
    {
        if(base.Connected)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM *** WHERE (**** = @user AND **** = @sifre)", connDB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sifre", pw);
            int valid = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (valid > 0)
            { return true; }
            else { return false; }
        } else { Writer.Hata_Log("Veritabanı Bağlantısı Yok."); return false; }

    }
}
```

My main thread executes Baglan() void then when i want to execute GirisKontrol from Islem it always return false with DB Connection not exist. Which i checked from public bool Connected at Baglanti Class

Comment: looks like you need a shared property, try making it `static`

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with the concept of object instances. Yes, you have one Baglanti class (better: type). But you have essentially what are two or more separate Baglanti instances (to be accurate, you have one or more DB instances and one or more Islem instances, each of them separate of each other). An analogue: There is one car type Ford Taurus. And there are thousands of instances of this one Taurus type on the streets. All of the same type -- but that does not mean they automatically share the driver, passengers, or luggage, right?

Comment: That said, i agree with Ehsan's suggestion as a quick fix. However, i think the real issue is that you have structured your code poorly. Class Islem seems to be *using* a database, whereas class DB seems to *represent* the database (based on the functionality displayed in the code of your question). But you have made your class design/inheritance like both classes represent/aggregate a database connection. Which is a pretty strong code smell..